are there any analytical techniques that differentiate alpha and beta sugars?
I have an upcoming lab where we will methylate ribose at different temperatures for different amounts of time, and then our products will be sent to the graduate students so they can determine the concentration of alpha and beta pyranosides and furanosides. The method listed was GCMS but that doesnt make sense, as the only difference is the hydroxyl group position and number of ring members. how could GCMS possinly be the right choice for this experiment?

Why wouldn't it make sense? Chromatographic methods can resolve even enantiomers, if chiral stationary phase is employed.

These are diastereomers. In principle, they can have different retention times and different fragmentation patterns. GCMS is able to separate and identify all componds in this mixture, for example.

Your question makes sense if we realize the fact that most sugars when heated become charred molasses. It is not possible to bring sugars in the gas phase. So where is GC coming from? Yet sugars can be analyzed by GC if and only if we convert them into volatile molecules. This is usually achieved by quantitatively converting into trifluoro derivatives by powerful reagents that react with the hydroxyl groups. So all -OH groups are gone, before analyzing them on GC using a MS detector. As Karsten hinted, diastereomers can be readily separated even on achiral columns.
Why not LC-MS? Yes, this is certainly possible without needing derivatization but the instrumentation is more expensive than GC-MS.

OP mentioned they're methylating them.

Methylation is also fine but trifluoro- derivatization is better.

Yeah, should be more volatile, but also more expensive, I guess.
